# Elementary integral for square roots of trig functions?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

What's an easy way to calculate something like $\int \sqrt{1+\cos x} \text{ d}x$?

Comment: Often $\cos$ and $\sin$ have some nice identities that help you out with this kind of integrals

Comment: I + cos(x) = 2{cos(x)}^2

Comment: What about integrals like the square root of (a+bcosx)?

Answer (score 4):

Hint $1+\cos(x)=2\cos^2(x/2)$ so it becomes $$\sqrt{2}\int |\cos(x/2)|$$ which can be integrated in a better way.

Comment: actually it is $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}\int \left|\cos \frac{x}{2}\right|dx$

Comment: Oh yes you ate right